# Bypassing FRP on SM-T567v Samsung Tab E Questions

Tags: samsung, frp

My company currently has 70 Samsung Tab E's (model # SM-T567v) that are FRP locked that we are trying to repurpose but are currently not able to. I have 1 tab e that is currently unlocked.

I have watched and tried every youtube "solution" to bypassing the FRP I could find. None of them work. I and I cannot find the firmware version T567VVRU1CQHD to download and reflash with odin. I have tried a couple of software solutions like imyfone lockwiper but even that comes back saying cannot find country and firmware version.

Is there anyway I can essentially make an image of the one working tablet, put it on a micro sd card and then essentially reimage all of the other tablets? Would I have to root the devices? Can I even root the devices if FRP locked out?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already consulted our [frp tag wiki](/tags/frp/info)? (Most of our tags have such wiki pages, where we collected the "core data" from related questions; always worth checking ;)

Comment: Ive looked in there but it seems like from what im gathering else where is that this specific model to due being verizon 4g lte cant be rooted and cant be re-flashed without bricking it and losing the cell data capabilities. I cant find anything to confirm or deny this. But I cant attempt this process and waste the tablet in the process. Seeking any help I can get here.